# I can't seem to create a SQL Server database with Visual Studio in data connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, server, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a SQL Server database and then to use it to make a list with important stuff in it. I don't seem to make it work. I went to the toolbox, chose panel and then when I get into creating the server itself, it doesn't work as it is not showing me a server name and the database name needed for it to work. I tried to write them myself but it's still not working.

[image]

Both of them when I open the list don't show anything. I understood that is essential for it to show me things for it to work.

Comment: Have you installed SQL server on your machine e.g., SQLExpress or similar?

Comment: Have you tried actually putting the name of the instance in the appropriate box?

Comment: If you type in localhost for server name, does it show you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could install `LocalDB` through the [Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), as part of the Data Storage and Processing workload, the ASP.NET and web development workload, or as an individual component.

[image]

After you install it, you could get it directly.

Here is the full [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16) about `LocalDB`.

You can also refer to this set of ssdt database operation process to learn [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272702(v=vs.103)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @נועם ורדי, Does it solve your problem? If you have question about it, please comment below.